# Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module) while using arduinojson

Tags: https, http-post, arduino-esp8266, arduinojson

I got this error after upgrading Arduinojson to 6.21.3, what I am supposed to do?
I kept changing the version for the Arduinojson but it ended with the same error, and before adding the Arduinojson part everything was working.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <FirebaseESP8266.h>
#include "location.h"
//http 
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
//Deserialize the JSON string
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// Firebase project configuration
#define FIREBASE_HOST ""
#define FIREBASE_AUTH ""


#define WIFI_SSID ""
#define WIFI_PASSWORD ""


// Google API keys
String geolocationKey = "";
String geocodingKey = "";

// From http://www.mcc-mnc.com/
int MCC = 602;  // Egypt Country Code
int MNC = 4;    // Egypt Network Code
String carrier = "WE";

FirebaseData firebaseData;
FirebaseJson json;
Location myLocation;

// GPS Module RX pin to NodeMCU D1
// GPS Module TX pin to NodeMCU D2
const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 5;
SoftwareSerial neo6m(RXPin, TXPin);
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// Relay pin
#define relayPin D8

// http variables

const char* serverAddress = "url";
const int serverPort = 443;
String scooter_code = "z1";

WiFiClientSecure client;
HTTPClient https;

float latitude , longitude;
//String  lat_str , lng_str, speed_str;
String Speed="0";
String battery="0";

String endpoint = "/api/scooters/"+scooter_code+"/update-live-details";
String requestBody;
String payload;



void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
neo6m.begin(9600);
pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT); // Set relay pin as an output
wifiConnect();
Serial.println("Connecting Firebase.....");
Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
Serial.println("Firebase OK.");
myLocation.begin(geolocationKey, geocodingKey, MCC, MNC, carrier);
digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW); // Set the relay to LOW initially
  // String  scooterStatus="0";


}

void loop() {

smartdelay_gps(1000);
  
if (gps.location.isValid()) {           // From GPS <=============================
   latitude = gps.location.lat();
   longitude = gps.location.lng();

    Serial.print("latitude is: ");
    Serial.println(latitude);
    Serial.print("longitude is: ");
    Serial.println(longitude);

    if (gps.speed.isValid()){
        int sped= gps.speed.kmph();
        Speed = String(sped);
        } else {
          Speed= "Unable to get the speed!";  
      }
    requestBody =  "{"
                       "\"speed\": " +Speed+","
                       "\"current_latitude\": " +latitude+","
                       "\"current_longitude\": " +longitude+","
                       "\"battery_level\": " +battery+
                       "}";
    Serial.println(requestBody);
    // Disable certificate verification
    client.setInsecure();

    if (https.begin(client, serverAddress, serverPort, endpoint)) {
        https.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        https.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        int httpResponseCode = https.POST(requestBody);
    
        if (httpResponseCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
          Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        } else {
          Serial.print("POST request failed with error code: ");
          Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        }
    
        https.end();
    } else {
      Serial.println("Unable to connect to the server");
    }
  
// This part to be removed ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, "/GPS/f_latitude", latitude)) {
    print_ok();
  } else {
    print_fail();
  }

  if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, "/GPS/f_longitude", longitude)) {
    print_ok();
  } else {
    print_fail();
  }
// until her -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
} else {
  myLocation.getLocation();    // From Geo location <=============================
  latitude = myLocation.latitude;
  longitude = myLocation.longitude;

  requestBody =  "{"
                     "\"speed\": " +Speed+","
                     "\"current_latitude\": " +latitude+","
                     "\"current_longitude\": " +longitude+","
                     "\"battery_level\": " +battery+
                     "}";
    
    // Disable certificate verification
    client.setInsecure();

  if (https.begin(client, serverAddress, serverPort, endpoint)) {
    https.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    https.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    int httpResponseCode = https.POST(requestBody);

    if (httpResponseCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      payload = https.getString();
      Serial.println("Here is the payload");
      Serial.println("payload data: " + payload );
      
                  // String input;
          
          StaticJsonDocument<192> doc;
          
          DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
          
          if (error) {
            Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
            Serial.println(error.c_str());
            return;
          }
          
          const char* status = doc["status"]; // "Data updated successfully"
          
          const char* action_name = doc["action"]["name"]; // "set_speed_limit"
          int action_value = doc["action"]["value"]; // 12
          


    } else {
      Serial.print("POST request failed with error code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    }

    


    https.end();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unable to connect to the server");
  }


// This part to be removed ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, "/Geolocation/latitude", myLocation.latitude)) {
    print_ok();
  } else {
    print_fail();
  }

  if (Firebase.setFloat(firebaseData, "/Geolocation/longitude", myLocation.longitude)) {
    print_ok();
  } else {
    print_fail();
  }
// until her -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}

Scooter_Relay();

delay(5000);


}

static void smartdelay_gps(unsigned long ms) {
unsigned long start = millis();
do {
  while (neo6m.available())
    gps.encode(neo6m.read());
} while (millis() - start < ms);
}

void wifiConnect() {
WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  Serial.print(".");
  delay(300);
}
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
Serial.println();
}

void print_ok() {
Serial.println("------------------------------------");
Serial.println("OK");
Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
Serial.println("TYPE: " + firebaseData.dataType());
Serial.println("ETag: " + firebaseData.ETag());
Serial.println("------------------------------------");
Serial.println();
}

void print_fail() {
Serial.println("------------------------------------");
Serial.println("FAILED");
Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
Serial.println("------------------------------------");
Serial.println();
}

void Scooter_Relay() {
 String  scooterStatus="0";

  // Check and control the scooter status
  if (Firebase.getString(firebaseData, "/Scooter/Status")) {
    scooterStatus = firebaseData.stringData();  // Get the string data
  } else {
    print_fail();
  }

  if (!scooterStatus.isEmpty()) {
    if (scooterStatus == "1") {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH); // Set the relay to HIGH
    } else if (scooterStatus == "0") {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW); // Set the relay to LOW
    }
  }

Serial.print("Scooter Status: ");
Serial.println(scooterStatus);

 }
```

**Here is the Error I got, some people says that the esp8266 is not compatible with the ArduinojSON version, if so what version of the lib should I use**

```
C:\Users\haidi\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Location\location.cpp:37:1: error: 'DynamicJsonBuffer' does not name a type
   37 | DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(320);
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\haidi\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Location\location.cpp: In member function 'void Location::geolocation()':
C:\Users\haidi\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Location\location.cpp:157:24: error: 'jsonBuffer' was not declared in this scope
  157 |     JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\haidi\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Location\location.cpp:158:13: error: 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject' {aka 'class ArduinoJson690_000::ObjectRef'} has no member named 'success'
  158 |     if(root.success()){
      |             ^~~~~~~
C:\Users\haidi\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Location\location.cpp: In member function 'void Location::geocoding()':
C:\Users\haidi\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Location\location.cpp:202:24: error: 'jsonBuffer' was not declared in this scope
  202 |     JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\haidi\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Location\location.cpp:203:13: error: 'ArduinoJson::JsonObject' {aka 'class ArduinoJson690_000::ObjectRef'} has no member named 'success'
  203 |     if(root.success()){
      |             ^~~~~~~
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

Comment: The "location.cpp" that you didn't shown us is using ArduinoJson 5.0 API, You either downgrade your ArduinoJson library to 5.0 or modify the "location.cpp" to the ArduinoJson 6.0 API. See [Migrating from version 5 to 6](https://arduinojson.org/v6/doc/upgrade/).